# Check if variable string have a match with a element from a list

Tags: python, string, list, variables

What i want is simple, but at the same time complex

```py
import re

list1 = ['developer 1', 'bot_add 1', 'sv_gravity 1000']
line = 'sv_gravity 800'

r = re.compile(line)
newlist = list(filter(r.match, list1))
separator  = ''
line = (separator.join(newlist))
print(line)
```

So, if the line variable have a match in list1, i want to change his value

so line should be : line = sv_gravity 1000

but the output is NOTHING, a blank space

If i change the line value for only "sv_gravity" the output will be "sv_gravity 1000", what is what i want.

Comment: what's the criteria for a match here? if `line = '1'` what would the answer be?

Comment: `line = '1'` will be '1', because is not in LIST1.

but if `line = '12345'` and `list1 = ['1234567']` This is a match and line now should be `line = '1234567'`

Comment: you need to say what is a match here? `'1'` is in every element of your example `list1`- or do you mean it has to start with the substring? what would `line = 'd'` show?

Comment: that's right, `'1'` is in list1 three times, but it shouldn't be a match.
I will explain in another way. `line = sv_gravity'` should be match, `line = sv_` isnt match, `line = sv_gravi` still not match. In your case `line = d` shouldnt be match too

Comment: If `line = developer 0` and `list1 contain developer 1`, now ` `line should be = developer 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to get simpler using list comprehension:

```
line = [i for i in list1 if line.split()[0] in i][0]
```

I assume you want to compare `'sv_gravity'` only so it works regardless of whether you have `'sv_gravity'` or `'sv_gravity 1000'` . It just compares the starting word (till a space is encountered) if it is in the list or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
   from difflib import get_close_matches 

   def closeMatches(patterns, word): 
        print(get_close_matches(word, patterns)) 

   closeMatches(patterns=list1, word=line)
```

You can use the above code to get your desired result. In your code because 'sv_gravity 800' is considered as a one string and therefore it is not finding the match in the list.
Even if you try 'sv_gravity  ' it will give you empty list.